# ReWrite text file

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

How to rewrite text file (at specificated position) and lock him?

For rewrite it need read and then to be written. - it is easy - but I need make file to be locked to all other process in the whole rewriting.

I have method.

```
    public bool AccessBridge()
    {
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream("bridge.ini", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then another test part:

```
        string precteno = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //Some modify string
        //now I need delete whole text from file
        sw.Write(precteno);
```

Any ideas? I have deal with it 2nd night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After idea of own Stream, I disassembly FileStream and discovered getter/setter Position.

Solution:

```
    string precteno = sr.ReadToEnd();
    precteno = stringModificator(precteno);
    fs.Position = 3;
    sw.Write(precteno);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FileShare.None` to open it exclusively:

```
fs = new FileStream("bridge.ini", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

As an aside... if I were you, I'd wrap that part in `using`:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("bridge.ini", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
}
```

That way, stream is properly disposed of.  Currently, I don't see anywhere in your code where you close your streams (maybe you're doing it somewhere else, since you've declared your streams outside of that method... but yeah).

Comment: This is really a good practice but didnt solve the problem.  How to clear a file using the same stream?

Comment: @IgorQuirino Solve what problem?  The question was in regards to locking the file.   Did that code not do it?

Comment: Lock file during whole rewriting. Open stream itself lock it. There is no implementation to rewrite, so I need read it and then write it  - and here is a problem. So question is: How to clear a file using the same stream?

Comment: @K.Zdenek It can all be done in one stream.  You open the FileStream with FileShare.None, which locks it.  You use StreamReader to read from the stream and StreamWriter to write to the stream.  So, I'm not sure what you're having issues with.

Comment: @B.K. When you read it by StreamReader whenever, writing starts at the end position of text file. FileShare.None used (default value is read). Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public bool AccessBridge()
{
    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream("bridge.ini", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite); 
        sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //do text modifications
        //... 
        sw = new StreamWriter(fs, false);
        sw. Write(text) ;
        return true;

    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does'nt work because there is no constructior for it. (work just with string path)